# How i can play audio in html?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

```html
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto"> 
 <source src="src/audio/blog_audio/music_file.ogg"  type="audio/ogg" /> 
 Your browser does not support the audio element. 
 <source src="src/audio/blog_audio/music_file.mp3"  type="audio/mp3" /> 
 Your browser does not support the audio element. 
 <source src="src/audio/blog_audio/music_file.aac"  type="audio/aac" /> 
 Your browser does not support the audio element. 
</audio>
```

I searched a lot here for a solution to the problem of playing the audio in the html5 file not working, and I did not find a solution to my problem, so I want to repeat the question in another form: the audio file works on the device or local host, but after uploading to the server it does not work.
I think the code is written correctly and I don't know how to solve it
*****I modified the mp3 audio file type to type="audio/mpeg"*****

This is the console error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Sot.jpg

Please help to solve the problem

Thank you all

Comment: Is the path correct on the server? (You're using a relative path.) How do you "upload to the server"? Do you see errors in your browser's network inspector?

Comment: No, there is no error in the file path and the code is written correctly, but it lacks the playback function in browsers

Comment: Sorry, there's an error in the console that I haven't noticed , https://imgur.com/gallery/GUS48j2

Comment: The 403 is an error with the permissions, you can learn more about it [Here](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-403-forbidden-error-and-how-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not from your code. The problem appear because you **don't set the correct permissions for the file**, this is why you get a **403 error** and you can't play audio files on your page.

*(I know my answer is a little bit blur, hope someone else could help you better ...)*

Comment: You're right, I turned off mod security and the audio file is working, but a new issue will appear which is site security in the future.. is there a way to exclude only audio files from mod security? e.g. htaccess

Comment: @HatemFrere Please mark this as a correct answer so others know it works if they also have a similar problem. **PS:** Site security is a different question with a different answer (so you must ask a new one about that problem)